# Looping through elements added on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

If for example I have the following HTML structure

```
<ul class="actions">
    <li class="action">Action 1</li>
    <li class="action">Action 2</li>
    <li class="action">Action 3</li>
</ul>
```

And the following Javascript

```
$('.actions .action').each( function() {
    perform an ajax request // intended pseudocode
    if ajax returns some more actions { // intended pseudocode
            $('.installer-actions').append('<li class="action">Another Action</li>');
    }
});
```

The added `<li class="action">` elements are not included in the `each()` obviously. Is there a way I can involve them in the current loop or will I need to loop through again and ignore the original `.action` elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add them to the object that `each` is iterating ([the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) doesn't say what happens if you `add` to the existing set, so we can't rely on whatever it currently does), but you can readily enough break out your code to a function which you can call in both places:

```
$('.actions .action').each(doCoolThing);
function doCoolThing() {
    var newAction;

    // perform an ajax request // intended pseudocode
    if (ajax_returns_some_more_actions) { // intended pseudocode
        newAction = $('<li class="action">Another Action</li>');
        $('.installer-actions').append(newAction);
        doCoolThing.call(newAction[0]);
    }
}
```

There we're calling `doCoolThing` on the new action, making `this` within the call the new raw DOM element (just like `each` does).

It's worth noting, though, that your ajax request will be asynchronous (unless you set `async` to `false`, which is a bad idea), which could impact how you would structure things. We'd have to see real code for the pseudo-code above to help there, but the concept above is sound.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be included in the original set of matched elements, however you can create the element, set up your listeners etc and then append it:

```
if ajax returns some more actions { // intended pseudocode
    var element = $('<li class="action">Another Action</li>');
    element.someMethods();
    $('.installer-actions').append(element);
}
```